# What's wrong with this query? The output is always empty

Tags: sql, google-apps-script

I've a file with two sheets: 1. the data and 2. the results. The structure of data is

A           B        C 
4210     10       name
4210     11       surname
4210     22       telephone
4210     62       mail
4210     142     job
4212     10       name
4212     11       surname
4212     22       telephone
4212     62       mail
4212     142     job
4214     10      name
4214     11      surname
4214     22      telephone
4214     62      mail
4214     142      job
...     ...     ...

With a query i like to consolidate the dates on the sheet results like that

A           B           C                 D                 E          F
             10          11                22                62       142
4210     name     surname     telephone     mail     job
4212     name     surname     telephone     mail     job
4214     name     surname     telephone     mail     job
...     ...     ...     ...       ...   ...

My query is:

```
=Query(data!$A1:$C12361;"SELECT C WHERE A='"&$A$2&"' and B='"&B1&"'")
```

And for the other fields with other variables.

It always returns empty output ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query has single quotes in it which would be required for matching strings. But you are matching integers which do not require the single quotes.

So instead of

```
"SELECT C WHERE A='4210'...
```

it should be

```
"SELECT C WHERE A=4210...
```

So the query would change to

```
"SELECT C WHERE A="&$A$2&" and B="&B1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your where clause doesn't qualify.
To properly debug what you're doing wrong, start out with a simpler where clause. See if that qualifies, and then build onto it. Good luck.

Comment: the query is very simple, it looks only a little bit complicated because I use cell-names ... and I've tried it for some hours ... :)

Comment: Sure, but you should still write a query even simpler to where it does return something, and then build on to that.